# form preview security hash manipulation

Tags: django, forms, security, hash, preview

i have three integer fields in one of models as follows:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    min_age = models.IntegerField()
    max_age = models.IntegerField()
    savings = helpers.MoneyField()
```

MoneyField is a custom field that uses a widget which breaks down an amount (170000) into two dropdowns as 100000 (Lakhs) and (70000) Thousands in a form.

For the form where i use the above money field i have a `form preview` view which forces a user to preview the form before posting.

Using the same idea, i wanted to change the `min_age` and `max_age` to use a single widget. so I,

1. Added a AgeFields (multi value field as follows):

   class AgeField(forms.MultiValueField):

   ```
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       """ 
       Have to pass a list of field types to the constructor, else we
       won't get any data to our compress method.
       """

       all_fields = ( 
           forms.CharField(),
           forms.CharField(),
           )   
       super(AgeField, self).__init__(all_fields, *args, **kwargs)

   def compress(self, values):
       if values:
           print values
           return '|'.join(values)
       return ''
   ```

Then in the Form, i made the model fields hidden and uses the above field to use a custom widget that looks similar to the `MoneyWidget()`

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    age = AgeField(widget=widgets.AgeWidget(),
            required=False)

    def is_valid(self):
        return super(PostForm, self).is_valid()

    def full_clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print self.data
        if 'age_0' in self.data:
            newdata = self.data.copy()
            newdata['min_age'] = self.data['age_0']
            newdata['max_age'] = self.data['age_1']
            print newdata
            self.data = newdata
        super(PostForm, self).full_clean(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = models.SomeModel
        fields = (
                  'age', 'min_age', 'max_age',
                  'savings'
                 )
        widgets = {
            'min_age' : forms.HiddenInput(),
            'max_age' : forms.HiddenInput(),
            'savings' : widgets.MoneyWidget(),
        }
```

Everything currently works expected, Though the `FormPreview` creates a loop. As i am using the `full_clean` method above to insert value into actual model fields.

So here is what happens.

1. A user fills out a form and click, Preview.
2. This creates a `security_hash` for that particular form and renders the preview view.
3. if the form is ok, user submits the form again else he click on the edit button to edit the form again.

Now in case the form is ok, and user clicks on a submit button, the formpreview instead of submitting the form loops back to the preview. Then on clicking the submit button again on the preview template the form gets submitted.

Most probably this is because we set the values of `min_age` and `max_age` in the full_clean method above after the security_hash was generated. the above method changes the security_hash as we are manipulating the data.

The second time, a user submits the form. `min_age` and `max_age` field already have the same data so the `security_hash` remains the same.

Is there any way we could manipulate the security_hash, or may be insert the values to min_age and max_age before the security_hash is generated. so that it remains the same ?

What would be the best approach to achieve the above ?

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

### Update:

I tried to dig in a little deeper and as i was assuming that the security hash was failing. So in order to be sure i over-rid the `failed_hash()` method to print an error message before calling the `preview_post()` view for `FormPreview` and guess what this was the method that was being called and redirecting the form back to the `preview_post()` method.

I thought the security hash was failing to match as i was manipulating the `POST` data in the above `full_clean()` method, so i set the min_age and max_age `required=False` and then tried explicitly setting the values in the `save()` method as follows

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'age_0' in self.data:
        newdata = self.data.copy()
        newdata['min_age'] = self.data['age_0']
        newdata['max_age'] = self.data['age_1']
        self.data = newdata
    super(PostForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for key in self.fields:
        self.fields['min_age'].required = False
        self.fields['max_age'].required = False
```

But still no luck. The `failed_hash()` method is still being called and the loop still exists. :(